# IntelliJ IDEA: Enable Annotation processors by default

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, annotation-processor

How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA to have Annotation processors enabled by default?

Currently, I have to enable it manually for every imported project.

[image: enable annotation processor]

Comment: Do you import the project from Maven or Gradle?

Comment: @CrazyCoder mostly - gradle. I just want this flag to be checked by default. There should not be any issues if there are no annotation processors on classpath.

Comment: Did you try File | Other Settings | Default Settings and enable it there before importing?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you. I did not know about _File | Other Settings | Default Settings_. This seems to be an answer to mu question.

Comment: IntelliJ has started asking this every time I open the IDE in 2020.2.

Comment: Why it is not turned on by default like in javac or in Maven compiler?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Current IDE version:

`File` | `New Projects Setup` | `Settings for New Projects...`, navigate to the compiler settings, annotation processing and enable this option before importing the project.

Previous versions:

`File` | `Other Settings` | `Default Settings`, navigate to the compiler settings, annotation processing and enable this option before importing the project.

Comment: After installing new Intellij 2018.2, I got the same problem. Default setting has already been set to correct value. But problem resolved only after File/Invalidate caches/Invalidate and restart

Comment: in 2019.1 there is no default settings anymore... so how we can achieve this?

Comment: @Arcones File | Other Settings | Settings for the new projects.

Comment: there is no "Other Settings" menu under "File" menu. Does its location changed?

Comment: It's, now, File -> New Projects Setup -> Preferences for New Projects...

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1**

from above version of Android Studio the position to *Annotation Processor* is as follows

[image]