# IntelliJ IDEA compilation error with Lombok

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a SpringBoot project with Lombok using the integrated development environment IntelliJ IDEA,  with this object:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;


}
```

and also this object:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

..

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.forEach(ur -> authorities.add(new Authority(ur.getRole().getName())));
        return authorities;
    }

..
}
```

but I have a compilation error:

[image]

but when I compile the project using maven everything is fine

Comment: install the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install lombok plugin and restart the IDEA , hope will work. You can follow the steps below:

1. Go to **File > Settings > Plugins**
2. Click on **Browse repositories**
3. Search **Lombok**
4. Click on Install plugin
5. Restart IntelliJ IDEA
6. clean build the project
7. If still doesn't work, go to **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you enable annotation processing, and install intelij lombok plugin

See this one [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452482/enable-annotation-processors-by-default)