# How to make Intellij IDEA to check annotate for all default?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Intellij IDEA]

I have to check `Annotate` one by one manually to see the last commit date and author, wondering how to make this `Annotate` checked for all default? just like `Show Line Numbers`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable Annotation processors by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452482/enable-annotation-processors-by-default)

Comment: does not work even invalid cache and restart, maybe only effective for new projects, i think i can check it later